# How can I reference other actions from my GitHub Action's action.yml file?

Tags: github-actions

Is it possible to reference another GitHub Action from my `action.yml` file?

Note, I'm talking about an action here, not a workflow. I know this can be done with workflows, but can actions reference other actions?

Comment: What you can do in `action.yml` seems to be deliberately limited so I imagine it's not possible, but could you explain more about what you are trying to do and your use-case. There might be a different way to achieve the same effect.

Comment: Looks like support for this is on the way: you can track progress in https://github.com/actions/runner/issues/646.

Comment: From #646, child issue for referencing actions from other actions: https://github.com/actions/runner/pull/612

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The answer seems to be: You can (now, Aug. 2021)

> ### [GitHub Actions: Reduce duplication with action composition](https://github.blog/changelog/2021-08-25-github-actions-reduce-duplication-with-action-composition/)

> Previously, actions written in YAML could only use scripts.
>
> Now, they can also reference other actions.
> This makes it easy to reduce duplication in your workflows.
>
> For example, the following action uses 3 actions to setup `buildx`, log in to Docker, and publish an image.
> By combining these into a single action it provides a larger unit of reuse that you can put into the job of any workflow.
>
> ```yaml
> name: "Publish to Docker"
> description: "Pushes built artifacts to Docker"
>
> inputs:
>  registry_username:
>    description: “Username for image registry”
>    required: true
>  registry_password:
>    description: “Password for image registry”
>    required: true
>
> runs:
>  using: "composite"
>  steps:
>      - uses: docker/setup-buildx-action@v1
>
>      - uses: docker/login-action@v1
>        with:
>          username: ${{inputs.registry_username}}
>          password: ${{inputs.registry_password}}
>
>      - uses: docker/build-push-action@v2
>        with:
>          context: .
>          push: true
>          tags: user/app:latest
> ```
>
> Developers can then reference this action in all of their repositories as a single action:
>
> ```yaml
> on: [push]
>
> jobs:
>  publish:
>    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
>    steps:
>      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
>      - uses: my-org/publish-docker@v1
>        with:
>          registry_username: ${{secrets.REGISTRY_USERNAME}}
>          registry_password: ${{secrets.REGISTRY_PASSWORD}}
> ```
>
> Learn more about [action composition](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/creating-actions/creating-a-composite-action).

So, as described in "[runs for composite actions](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/creating-actions/metadata-syntax-for-github-actions#runs-for-composite-actions)":

> ### `runs.steps[*].uses`
>
> [Optional] Selects an action to run as part of a step in your job.
>
> **An action is a reusable unit of code**.
> You can use an action defined in the same repository as the workflow, a public repository, or in a published Docker container image.
>
> We strongly recommend that you include the version of the action you are using by specifying a Git ref, SHA, or Docker tag number.
> If you don't specify a version, it could break your workflows or cause unexpected behavior when the action owner publishes an update.
>
> ```yaml
> runs:
>  using: "composite"
>  steps:
>    # Reference a specific commit
>    - uses: actions/checkout@a81bbbf8298c0fa03ea29cdc473d45769f953675
>    # Reference the major version of a release
>    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
>    # Reference a specific version
>    - uses: actions/checkout@v2.2.0
>    # Reference a branch
>    - uses: actions/checkout@main
>    # References a subdirectory in a public GitHub repository at a specific branch, ref, or SHA
>    - uses: actions/aws/ec2@main
>    # References a local action
>    - uses: ./.github/actions/my-action
>    # References a docker public registry action
>    - uses: docker://gcr.io/cloud-builders/gradle
>    # Reference a docker image published on docker hub
>    - uses: docker://alpine:3.8
> ```

Answer (score 4):

The answer seems to be: You can't.

However, I ended up internally downloading the different actions from NPM, and then re-using them within my own action.

Probably not a good idea in general, but this particular action I am making is designed to run on my own projects without requiring too much configuration, so that makes it more okay.

Comment: Could you give an example for this? I'm having trouble passing parameters as well as I'm not sure how different parts of the action could be called, i.e. https://github.com/actions/cache/blob/23e301d35cb55b348f1f4524e353b1fc29567e5f/action.yml#L19-L20

Answer (score 3):

If both actions are nodejs actions you are serving over GitHub and you don't mind them reading the one set of input, this works pretty well:

```sh
npm install --save MyGitHubOrg/MyRepo#master
git add -f node_modules/ package.json package-lock.json
```

```js
async function run() {
    try {
        require('my-action');
    } catch (err) {
        core.setFailed(`Failed to run habitat-action: ${err.message}`);
        return;
    }

    // ...
}
```

Comment: This will lock you into a specific version though, it might be better to run `npm install` with a configurable version as part of the action.

Comment: it is not advised to add node modules to git