# Call a github action from another github action?

Tags: github-actions

Is it possible to call one (or many) github action from a github action to create a more specialized one, or aggregate many small actions and create a "meta github action" ?

Comment: GitHub is still developing this: https://github.com/actions/runner/pull/612 https://github.com/actions/runner/issues/646

Comment: Github has [developed it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68933084/6309) (since Aug. 2021)

Answer (score 6):

There is no built-in feature to do this that I'm aware of.

This is a related question where the original poster replied with a workaround that involves using the NPM packages published from other actions.
[How can I reference other actions from my GitHub Action's action.yml file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58611841/how-can-i-reference-other-actions-from-my-github-actions-action-yml-file)

I have a similar situation in which I would like [`actions/setup-python` to be released as an NPM package](https://github.com/actions/setup-python/issues/38) so I can use it in my Javascript action.

Answer (score 2):

It is not officially supported, but when there is no licensing issue you could pick any of the following options:

1. the easiest is to just add to your action repository the single .js file (with all dependencies embedded, usually packed by [ncc](https://github.com/zeit/ncc)) that most of the actions provides under the `/dist/` directory; then simply set the `INPUT_*` you desire and launch it such as `node action.js`.
2. or, you can add the desired action you want to use in your own action's repository as a *subrepo* (or a *subtree*, but **not** as a *submodule* as the latter are would not be fetched along with your action repo), and launch it with 'node' from your action as I have done for my [run-vcpkg](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/run-vcpkg) and [get-cmake](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/get-cmake) GitHub actions.