# How do you use a composite action that exists in a private repository?

Tags: github, repository, github-actions

We have a bunch of health checks against third-party services. We want them to run periodically because when they go down it affects our app just like a bug in our code. Knowing that "it's them not us" reduces significant troubleshooting time.

We've set this health check up via github actions with a scheduled run, but we want a HealthCheck per third-party service. That way, the slack message on failure will be very specific of what is down. But that is going to create a lot of duplicated yml content.

I discovered something called [github composite actions](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/creating-actions/creating-a-composite-action) and it seems to be intended for solving this problem, but I can't find information about whether or not a composite action can live in a private repository.

[The documentation of the `uses` key](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/creating-actions/metadata-syntax-for-github-actions#runsstepsuses) only mentions public repositories when it mentions repositories at all. Is there a way to make a composite action in a private repository and use it?

I tried making their hello world example, ran it, and it ran correctly. Then I made the action repo private, and the repo using the action's build failed saying:

```
Unable to resolve action `user/repo@v1`, repository not found
```

Comment: You have to check out the repo with the private action using a personal access token, and then use `uses:` with a relative path to the action (starting with `./`). Not sure if "composite" actually solves your need to parametrize what's happening.

Comment: @BenjaminW. why do you say composite doesn't solve my need? BTW, I don't even know if this is possible, but I want to parameterize a bash command string.

Comment: I'll add an answer about using an action from a private repo, the use case seems to be a separate question.

Comment: @BenjaminW. it's a separate question, but it's already been asked and the [answer I found was to use a composite action.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58611841/how-can-i-reference-other-actions-from-my-github-actions-action-yml-file) If you know a better solution to this problem, can you tell me what it is?

Comment: Oh, now I understand. Yes, using actions within composite actions has been enabled just two weeks ago or so. Before, they were called "composite run steps actions" and were exactly that, `run:` steps aggregated into an action. So far I've only seen [this issue comment](https://github.com/actions/runner/issues/646#issuecomment-901336347), with the official docs and changelog still to come.

Comment: Oh, changelog is now there: https://github.blog/changelog/2021-08-25-github-actions-reduce-duplication-with-action-composition/ - looks like the issue comment has outdated links.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I used [this little example](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/creating-actions/creating-a-composite-action) of composite actions from GitHub and modified it to use my private repository building on Benjamin's excellent answer.

```
jobs:
  hello_world_job:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    name: A job to say hello
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Get composite run steps repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          # action file is located in another repo called workflows at /workflows/actions/action.yaml
          repository: my-org/workflows
          #  ref: mybranch  # in case it's not master branch
          # use deploy key instead of personal access token
          ssh-key: ${{ secrets.WORKFLOWS_DEPLOYMENT_KEY }}
          path: .github/workflows
      - id: foo
        uses: ./.github/workflows/actions
        with:
          who-to-greet: 'Mona the Octocat'
      - run: echo random-number ${{ steps.foo.outputs.random-number }}
        shell: bash
```

A few caveats:

- Don't use personal access token. It's not recommended for this use case. Instead, create a deployment key as described [here](https://docs.github.com/en/developers/overview/managing-deploy-keys#deploy-keys) to access one specific repository where your actions are stored
- Don't use `actions/checkout` inside your composite action yaml. Post action will fail even if the action itself succeeds

Comment: Excellent, thanks for adding this! The super broad permissions on the PAT have always felt dirty.

Answer (score 13):

*Update (February 2023): this is now possible without jumping through any extra hoops, making [Debos' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74893638/3266847) by far the most simple way.*

---

*The recent [answer added by gmode](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72915507/3266847) uses an SSH key instead of a personal access token, avoiding the problem of the overly broad permissions granted by the PAT, and I recommend to use that approach over the one described in my answer here.*

---

Original answer:

You have to check out the repository containing your action using a personal access token first, then use a relative path to where you checked it out:

```yaml
- name: Check out main repository
  uses: actions/checkout@v2

- name: Get composite run steps repository
  uses: actions/checkout@v2
  with:
    repository: myorg/myaction
    # Select revision
    ref: v1.0.0
    # Personal access token to check out private repository
    token: ${{ secrets.PAT_TOKEN }}
    # Indicate where to check action out to
    path: .github/myaction

- name: Run action from private repo
  uses: ./.github/myaction
```

This assumes that `myaction` is a repository with `action.yml` in its root directory. If that's not the case, the last `uses` step has to be adapted to use the correct path.

Notice that if you use [dependabot to update your actions](https://docs.github.com/en/code-security/supply-chain-security/keeping-your-dependencies-updated-automatically/keeping-your-actions-up-to-date-with-dependabot), the private action reference won't be updated.

At some point in the future, actions from internal repositories are going to be natively supported, see [this issue](https://github.com/github/roadmap/issues/74) from the GitHub roadmap, however as of October 2021 the issue was updated with the flag "github enterprise" meaning that it'll only be for GitHub Enterprise users.

Comment: won't that `path` overwrite the existing actions in there?

Comment: @DanielKaplan It should be a path to a non-existing directory, or else you do get clashes potentially. `.github/actions` isn't used by default, as far as I know.

Comment: ah right. I confused that with .github/workflows

Comment: @BenjaminW. This was very helpfull thanks. Just to note though: in the checkout step when you do path: .github/actions, it doesnt automatically create a subdirectory with the imported repo name. So to run the action as mentioned in the solution you need to use the path `uses: ./.github/actions` rather than `uses: ./.github/actions/myprivateaction`. (assuming action.yml is in root). Just pointing it out since it confused me a bit!

Comment: @Coockson Ah, good point, I used `myprivateaction` because In my use case for this, the imported repo contains multiple actions in a subdirectory each! If you do "one action per repo" with `action.yml` in the root directory, then yes. I'll update this because I believe the way you describe is the more common usage.

Comment: @BenjaminW. Do you have to do anything special in your composite action.yml file regarding Post? When we try your solution it runs correctly, but then has a "Post" job that fails, while looking for an action.yml file.

Comment: @davepreston Nothing that I can think of! The post step is just automated cleanup, as far as I know, no?

Comment: @Rocklan I had rolled back your edit because "cloud" is also simpy "github.com", but I notice that they also *removed* the "all" tag, so I rolled back the rollback ;)

Comment: Note that if the composite action is stored in a directory inside the same repository that's running the workflow, you don't need a separate checkout step, nor do you need a personal access token. You can simply create a separate .github/actions/my_local_action/action.yml for each local action, and you can call them all directly. (i.e. You just need the first 2 and last 2 lines of the answer in this case)

Comment: @davepreston Did you ever figure out your issue? I'm running up to the same thing, the post step failing for the action coming from the other repo because it can't find action.yml (which is there and used just fine in the action itself when it runs after checkout in the current repo).

Comment: I want to point out there are much more secure options than using a personal access token. A PAT gives the repo broad permissions to access all of your Github projects. Instead, a deploy key is much more secure and limits the repo to only be able to access the repo it needs. See https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/security-hardening-for-github-actions#considering-cross-repository-access For details. Aside from that, very useful info that I will be digging into. Thank you!

Comment: @jmort253 If you have a way to use an action from a private repository in a way that uses a deploy key and no personal access token, I'd love to see that as a separate answer. Not trying to be sarcastic or anything, I just never looked into it long enough to figure out if it's possible or not, but you're right, the repo scope on a PAT is concerningly broad.

Comment: @BenjaminW. Thanks for the suggestion.  I'll move it higher on my to-do list .  :)

Comment: `actions/checkout` supports `ssh-key` option where you can provide deployment key (private). Make sure to add public deployment key to the actions repository

Comment: @reintroducing @davepreston post step fails if your composite job contains `actions/checkout`. I added another answer with some tips

Comment: Proper sharing within an org, is now GA https://github.blog/changelog/2022-03-04-sharing-github-actions-within-your-enterprise-is-now-ga/

Comment: @kim0 But only for enterprise accounts :(

Comment: I believe that, as of December 2022, private actions can be used by any personal or team account and is no longer limited to enterprise accounts.  See https://github.blog/changelog/2022-12-14-github-actions-sharing-actions-and-reusable-workflows-from-private-repositories-is-now-ga/

Comment: @jamesmortensen Looks like that's the case indeed! I'll update accordingly.

Comment: @jamesmortensen Or actually, that would probably be an entirely new answer, in case you feel like writing one; I'll update this one to point out it's no longer required and recommend your approach instead.

Comment: ... there already is an answer for that :)

Answer (score 7):

Unless I'm missing something obvious since the 4th March the functionality was GA on dotcom as per [the previously tracked issue](https://github.com/github/roadmap/issues/74) making the above answer superseded. The only requirement now is for the private repo that contains the composites to allow access from other repos in the same org or enterprise. I hope it helps.

Comment: In March 2022, this was released as Enterprise-only ("internal repositories"), but it looks like since December 2022 it's now really possible to access actions from other private repos in non-Enterprise organizations.

Comment: @debo - Here's the changelog from GitHub announcing this becoming GA for all:  https://github.blog/changelog/2022-12-14-github-actions-sharing-actions-and-reusable-workflows-from-private-repositories-is-now-ga/

Comment: I just tested with with a private action being used from another private repository on a free account, and it works – definitely the most simple way now! I'll update my answer (again) to point to this one.

Comment: Can you add a code snippet similar to the top answer?

Comment: This answer is not very helpful. A snippet should suffice.

Comment: Please refer to the official announcement and documentation here https://github.blog/changelog/2022-03-04-sharing-github-actions-within-your-enterprise-is-now-ga/