# What do I need to do to clone a repo within the same org within a Github Actions workflow?

Tags: github, deployment, continuous-integration, github-actions, continuous-deployment

Does anyone have experience with Github Actions? Within a Github Actions workflow, I am trying to clone another internal repo within the same org. I am doing the below.

```yaml
- name: Install SSH Key
  uses: webfactory/ssh-agent@v0.5.4
  with:
        ssh-private-key: ${{ secrets.ACCESS_KEY }}

- name: Clone the internal repo
  uses: actions/checkout@v3
  with:
        repository: '[org name]/[repo name]'
        path: [my path]
        token: ${{ secrets.ACCESS_KEY }}
```

The `Access_Key` is a private key stored in the repo's secrets. The public part of the key is added to the internal repo (the repo I am trying to clone) as a deploy key.

The first step completes successfully, but it does log this:

> Comment for (public) key ' ' does not match GitHub URL pattern. Not treating it as a GitHub deploy key.

The second step fails with this error:

> token ... is not a legal HTTP header value

I'm not sure if the comment from the first step is causing a failure in the second or not. But I can't seem to fix either. Nor can I find really any documentation online to fix either of these. Does anyone have any ideas, advice, or experience with Github Actions, deploy keys, etc?

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72915507/3266847) is checking out a repo using an SSH key. I don't think you need your first step at all.

Comment: I still get the second error on the checkout step

Comment: Most likely you secret was not added to GitHub repo -> Settings > Secrets > Actions

Comment: Did you switch from `token` to `ssh-key`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. [Create a new secret](https://github.com/example/example/settings/secrets/actions) containing [GitHub access token](https://github.com/settings/tokens) with read permissions to the target repository
2. Use that token inside of your workflow (instead of `GITHUB_TOKEN`)

```
- uses: actions/checkout@v3
  with:
    repository: '[org name]/[repo name]'
    path: [my path]
    token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_AUTH_TOKEN }}
```

Alternatively, you can add another repo as [Git submodule](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules) to the main repo.

```
- uses: actions/checkout@v3
  with:
    submodules: '[submodules]'
```

Comment: That submodule idea is perfect. Thanks much